# How to use Yoast SEO backend in english even if WPLANG variable is not english?

Tags: wp-admin, front-end, translation, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

I added this code to my functions.php file

```
add_filter('locale', 'wpse27056_setLocale');
function wpse27056_setLocale($locale) {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        return 'en_US';
    }

    return $locale;
}
```

so the frontend is available in `ro_RO` and `wp-admin` is available in `en_US`

Well... that almost worked excepting Yoast's WordPress SEO plugin which is translated in romanian.

What can i do with that plugin to be displayed in english?

Answer (score 2):

That plugin loads its language the moment its main file is included:

```
load_plugin_textdomain( 'wordpress-seo', false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages' );
```

So when your `locale` filter is used, the language is already there. :/

Move your small plugin into the `mu-plugins` directory. You can create it if it doesn’t exists in `wp-content`. That should load your plugin earlier than Yoast’s.

Lesson: **Never load your language files before `wp_loaded`.**

Comment: where should i add this code? exactly in what file from `wp-content` ?

Comment: @m3tsys `wp-content/mu-plugins/fix-wpseo.php`

Comment: Why is `init` not sufficient? It runs after `load_textdomain`, after all.

Comment: @JohannesPille And this is why it is too late.

Comment: Now I'm confused. `wp_loaded` runs even later - and that's what you recommended not to load one's language files before.

Comment: @JohannesPille Oh, I misread your question, sorry. `init` runs before the spam blog check, it should always be skipped in favor of `wp_loaded`.

Answer (score 2):

There is even a better solution: a filter called [`plugin_locale`](http://wphooks.info/filters/plugin_locale/). It filters the locale argument before using it in `load_plugin_textdomain`.

```
add_filter( 'plugin_locale', 'mytheme_plugin_locale' );

function mytheme_plugin_locale() {
    return 'en_US';
}
```